# Protractor : Failed: Timed out waiting for asynchronous Angular tasks to finish after 11 seconds

Tags: angular, protractor, e2e-testing, angular-e2e

I'm getting below error:

> Failed: Timed out waiting for asynchronous Angular tasks to finish
>   after 11 seconds. This may be because the current page is not an
>   Angular application

I've seen similar question but none of them  seems to have a good solution

working on Angular 4

My setup is :
1) onBeforeLaunch :
         I'm using webdrive and chromedriver to fetch token for authentication

```
beforeLaunch(){

    const webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
    const chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome');
    const path = require('chromedriver').path;
// do stuff like get token save it in variable
driver.quit();
}
```

2) onPrepare

browser.params.tokens = token from before launch

3)

```
it('should authenticate',() => {
       browser.get('/home?'+browser.params.token)
       expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toContain('home');
})
```

on 3rd step its giving error.

PS: I've tried multiple option like ignoreSync, waitforangularenabled, sleep nothing worked can someone point to me what I'm doing wrong here

Comment: Why do you use `driver.quit()` in the beforeLaunch?

Comment: in onbefore I'm logging into headless chrome using lib mentioned so once my job is done, gettting token, I'm closing it.

Comment: So you see the browser getting started and open the page?

Comment: yes, everything works as expected only when it tries to run 'it', it fails

Comment: I suppose line `browser.get('/home?'+browser.params.token)` ends with a semicolon?

Answer (score 0):

Here is might the issue caused by the specific structure of your application. Because on default Protractor is waiting for your Angular application until Angular goes to so-called **'calm mode'**

*Before performing any action, Protractor waits until there are no pending asynchronous tasks in your Angular application. This means that all timeouts and http requests are finished.* -- this is **'calm mode'**

A lot of people encounter it, you can see a lot of questions on StackOverFlow, long time ago I also asked this question and then we resolved this stumble with my team.

At first, read it to know a basis:
https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/timeouts.md

In my turn, I will suggest you 2 options out of which you need to pick one.

1. In places where the test falls put `waitForAngularEnabled(false);` 
   and after some actions(which you will define while testing) return it by putting the same line of code with boolean true

   `waitForAngularEnabled(true)`

That means that you ordered your protractor not to wait for Angular to stop working and executing its working further and then in some point that you know Angular is stopping his work again, you are turning this parameter on again and Protractor will be waiting for Angular again. 
But it can be not the only one place where it might happen and if it is you need to go to the option 2

2. To have a discussion with your developers to change application in order Protractor would be able to run without obstacles.
   P.S this is the thing I made in my team, and they fixed out an application in order enable Protractor tests to work smoothly.